# Changing locale not working after `onResume` method?

Tags: android, onresume

I have an app that is (more or less) translated in other languages. For this I used `locale` and for saving the language preferred by the user I used `SharedPreferences`.

Using this I managed to load the prefered language on any/every activity inside the app.

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick);

    findViewById(R.id.flagcollection).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    findViewById(R.id.worldmapswitch)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (flagWorld) {
                        // means true
                        findViewById(R.id.flagcollection).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        flagWorld = false;
                    } else {
                        findViewById(R.id.flagcollection).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        flagWorld = true;
                    }
                }
            });

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("settings_values", MODE_PRIVATE);

    String SavedLocaleLang = preferences.getString("LocalLang", null);
    Locale locale = new Locale(SavedLocaleLang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
....
```

The problem is that if for whatever reason I leave the app (not exiting/ending activity), after a while when I return to the app, it runs using the PHONE'S default language and not the saved value for locale.

Then, after reading numerous posts regarding the miracles of onResume, combined with my java no-skills I tried this :

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("settings_values", MODE_PRIVATE);

    String SavedLocaleLang = preferences.getString("LocalLang", null);
    Locale locale = new Locale(SavedLocaleLang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


}
```

I thought that I have solved my problem, but after testing the result in less than 1 hour I realized that I've done nothing (at least nothing good). Somewhere I'm doing something wrong.

If anyone has the skills, the patience and much, much good will, PLEASE help me understand what and where I am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! No sarcasm though, please. There I'm doing just fine :P

THANK YOU !!!

P.S. User "Cochi" requested the code for saving the locale in Prefereces ... so here you go :

```
findViewById(R.id.flaghungary)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String localeHU = "hu";
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings_values", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("LocalLang", localeHU);
                    editor.apply();

                    Locale locale = new Locale("hu");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick);
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Magyar nyelv kiválasztva", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    recreate();
                }


            });
```

Comment: Most likely, your process was terminated while your app was in the background. [This is perfectly normal](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle). Beyond that, please explain what "Somewhere I'm doing something wrong" means.

Comment: My initial thought is are you calling `commit()` or `apply()` on the `SharedPreferences.Editor` object when saving the locale? It's a common oversight and the sharedPreferences will not be updated unless you do that.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your quick reply. I have updated the code from onCreate, as it was before. Now I'm trying Nika Kurdadze's solution. Maybe it works :D

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you are saving the locale in shared preferences please ?

Comment: @Cochi - I edited the main post, you can find the code at the bottom, by P.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting that code inside `onCreate`, before the `setContentView` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String SavedLocaleLang = preferences.getString("LocalLang", null);
    Locale locale = new Locale(SavedLocaleLang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: hello. Thank you but, I should have copied more from the onCreate method so you have a bigger picture. I have done that. Now I will try it your way :). Thank you for your suggestion, it takes a while until I can be sure it works, but be sure I leave a reply. Thank you again

Comment: Hi again. It seems that your solution works. Or at least I hope it does :) I tested the app all day long and no glitches found. yet :). so ... THANK YOU !

Comment: I'm glad this fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the fix